# CDialog DoModal (dialog opens with keyboard focus, but not mouse focus)

Tags: mfc, focus, mouse, cdialog, cricheditctrl

I have a CDialog window (CDrafter) which contains a CRichEditCtrl control.

I overrided CDrafter::PreTranslateMessage and CDrafter::OnNotify to allow me to click on special words in the RichTextEdit with the mouse, which in turn opens another dialog (MyDialog).

*NOTE: I did this as I didn't like the limitations of the EN_LINK styling.*

**So within the CDrafter::PreTranslateMessage i have:**

It just determines where and which word was clicked (nothing more) (waits for OnNotify to do something with it).

**So within the CDrafter::OnNotify I have:**

```
BOOL CSTANAGMessageDrafterDlg::OnNotify( WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pResult    )
{
    BOOL r = CDialog::OnNotify(wParam, lParam, pResult);

    //if (::PreTranslateMessage found a word clicked on ) {
    MyDialog dialog;
    dialog.DoModal();

    //}

    //Awesome my dialog opened and I can start editing the form (via the keyboard) no problems.
    //BUG: There is a problem as the mouse curser is still showing the 
    // move carpet position icon as if it is still focused on the RichTextEdit control.
    // If I click the mouse anywhere (in the MyDialog, or within the parent dialog)
    // the mouse icon, and focus correctly changes to MyDialog, then I can click OK or CANCEL. 



  return r;
}
```

I have tried the calling "CDialog::OnNotify(wParam, lParam, pResult)" after the MyDialog::DoModal - still see same issue. 
The MyDialog::DoModal is called within the same thread as the parent dialog.

I would expect to be able to do the following:

click on word, and MyDialog opens, click on MyDialog::Cancel button and the dialog closes.

But there is a problem as this is my sequence:

click on word, and MyDialog opens, **click on MyDialog::Cancel button (it doesn't work - only the mouse icon changes)**, click on MyDialog::Cancel button and the dialog closes

I need to (initially click) the mouse in order to get any mouse control within the newly opened dialog. i.e. the mouseover event on buttons, etc. does nothing until I (click).

Comment: There's no such thing as mouse focus, only keyboard focus. Are you simply complaining that the mouse cursor is wrong?

Comment: The cursor icon is wrong, but so is the functionality:  clicking on anything within MyDialog does not work for the first click. It works correctly after the first click.